# Restrict access to setter in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a service with some data feed by a Controller.
Now, I exposed that service to Twig by globally injecting it:

```
globals:
    my_service: '@AppBundle\Service\MyService'
```

How can I prevent someone working on the Twig page to call e.g.

```
my_service.setData('blah')?
```

As I'd only want the controller to write the data to it.
And I only want Twig to be able to read the data:

```
my_service.getData()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make another service, let's call it MyDataProvider, and make it read-only. Pseudocode:

```
AppBundle\DataProvider\MyDataProvider:
  $myService: '@AppBundle\Service\MyService'

globals:
    my_data_provider: '@AppBundle\DataProvider\MyDataProvider'
```

And then, only proxy the getters from MyService in MyDataProvider:

```
class MyDataProvider {
    private $myService;     

    public function __construct(MyService $myService) {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    // proxy allowed methods, use __get(), or anything else you like
    public function getWhatever() {
        return $this->myService->getWhatever();
    }

    // deny, throw exception, or don't implement at all
    public function setWhatever() {
        throw AccessDeniedException
    }
}
```

As for providing *all* other classes with MyService - you could inject it, or only provide to tagged services (as you note, only Controllers should write into it), whichever works for you.

Comment: Thanks, seems so obvious now :)